How to create an Array[T | Null] where T is a type parameter with `AnyRef` as upper bound
I need to create a temporary Array[T | Null] where T is a type parameter with AnyRef as upper bound.
Given the arrays implementation will use an Array[AnyRef] after erasure for whatever T is, why should I relay on a ClassTag?
def method[T <: AnyRef](elements: Iterable[T])(using ctTorNull: ClassTag[T | Null]): T = 

    val array = elements.toArray[T | Null]
    ???

}

Is there a way to achieve the same without using ClassTag nor asInstanceOf in scala 3.4?
Edit: As Dmytro pointed out in his answer, the type information that the JVM has about Array[A] and of Array[B] is different even if both A and B extend AnyRef.
Evidently, arrays hold more information about the declared type of their elements than many collections do. So, to avoid the ClassTag in this scenario use a mutable collection that does not require a ClassTag. mutable.ArraySeq requires it but ArrayBuffer does not.
The example below uses the IndexedSeq factory which creates an ArrayBuffer.
def method[T <: AnyRef](elements: Iterable[T]): T = 

    val array = scala.collections.mutable.IndexedSeq.from[T | Null](elements)
    ???

}

If for efficiency reasons you need that the temporary collection be an Array, you may avoid the contextual ClassTag parameter if the received collection exposes the ClassTag of its backing Array. mutable.ArraySeq and mutable.ArrayStack do it in the elemTag member.
def method[T <: AnyRef](elements: mutable.ArraySeq[T]): T = 

    val array = elements.toArray[T | Null](using elements.elemTag.asInstanceOf[ClassTag[T | Null]])(elements)
    ???
}

Here I assumed that the erased type of T and T | Null is the same when T <: AnyRef.


Given the arrays implementation will use an Array[AnyRef] after erasure for whatever T is


(where T is a type parameter with AnyRef as upper bound)

It's not true that erasure of Array[T] (T <: AnyRef) is Array[AnyRef]. See the spec:

The erasure of the parameterized type scala.Array[T]
is scala.Array[|T|].

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/3.4/03-types.html#type-erasure
(Here |T| denotes the erasure of T).
You can check that Array[Int] and Array[String] have different classes at runtime
classOf[Array[Int]])   // class [I
classOf[Array[String]] // class [Ljava.lang.String;

.asInstanceOf will throw if you specify wrong class
Array(1, 2, 3).asInstanceOf[Array[String]]
// java.lang.ClassCastException: class [I cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String;

Similarly,
class SomeClass
class OtherClass
implicitly[SomeClass <:< AnyRef] // compiles
implicitly[OtherClass <:< AnyRef] // compiles

classOf[Array[SomeClass]]) // class [LSomeClass;
classOf[Array[OtherClass]] // class [LOtherClass;

Array(new SomeClass()).asInstanceOf[Array[OtherClass]]
// java.lang.ClassCastException: [LSomeClass; cannot be cast to [LOtherClass;

It's T in Iterable[T] that is erased. So you need ClassTag to preserve the information about T from compile time to runtime (in order to get correct Array[T] at runtime).

You may be right, but your comparation with arrays of ints is not pertinent because Int does not extend AnyRef.
You took my frase out of context which removed the fact that T has AnyRef as upper bound.

I mean, when you quoted my sentence "Given the arrays implementation will use an Array[AnyRef] after erasure for whatever T is" you are omitting the condition I mentioned before that T has AnyRef as upper bound.

@Readren Ok, but with this restriction this statement is still wrong.

@Readren Because Array[String] is a subclass of Array[AnyRef] (classOf[Array[AnyRef]].isAssignableFrom(classOf[Array[String]]) is true), just different classes.

@Readren Ok, maybe I don't understand what you mean by "use". My point is that you need the information about T at runtime and you will not have it if you don't use something like ClassTag.

Exactly. I never asked the compiler to cast an array of elements of class A to an array of class B, but to an array elements of type A | Null.
classOf[String] shows the same than classOf[String|Null]

Forget what I said. My bad. I was confused.
I think your answer would be better if it only mentions the fact that the runtime class representation of Array[A] and of Array[B] are different event if both A and B extend AnyRef

I think the runtime representation of two AnyRef based arrays is not different on JVM, but Scala requires you to pass ClassTag anyway - it requires it any time it wants to contruct an Array.

Anyway, what struggles me is that if the temporary array in the method of my original question were declared and created as an Array[AnyRef] the method would be able to do the job because it does not access any method other than the ones in Object. But if the method also received a function that with a parameter of type T then I would have to cast from AnyRef to T on every call, which is safe.
Conclusion: The type information given by ClassTag is not needed but allows me avoid safe castings.

@Suma I believed the same. But apparently the JVM stores the erased form of the declared type information of their elements.

@DmytroMitin I edited the question adding an answer. Tell me if it is correct please.

I think adding answer in a question is not a good practice, it makes reading the question with answers confusing. If you want to add an answer, add an answer. :)
